# Packing generated image in Jar

Tags: java

I've created an application for Captcha but when I open the jar file an image file of the captcha code is generated alongside the jar. 
How do I pack this generated image in the jar?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. Care to share why you would like that to happen?

Comment: I can still broach an answer : a jar is a ZIP archive ; use classes of the `java.util.zip` package to manipulate it as such and update it to add a new binary file to its entries.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav as said by @Aaron, _"you probably shouldn't"_. This means that you would like to change the application that you are using. More or less like if you want to  save your documents in your text-editor executable.